# ADODB supported by Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, adodb

i wan to use ADODB components in my project, but i cant find adodb component in Visual Studio 2010, it supported by Visual Studio 2010??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADODB is wrapped by the classes in the System.Data.Oledb namespace.

If you are talking about the old VB6 components that you could put on a form then, no, their time has passed.  They are visible in the toolbox' Choose Items dialog, COM tab.  But trying to add them fails on my machine.  Probably because ADODB got a breaking update in Windows 7 SP1.  Nor would you have any good way to deploy them.